# Internet speed not up to the mark

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, speed

My internet package is 60mbps. When I check the speed of internet in my computer (which is connected directly to the ethernet port and the router) via speedtest.net (Ookla) its showing 60mbps which is perfectly alright. But when I check the speed of the other devices that are connected to the internet through WiFi, via the same website, its not crossing 20mbps. That too the speed is not at all consistent, it ranges anywhere between 0mbps(no internet) to 20mbps. Is my router spoiled?

Comment: No. This is a known problem when using WiFi. Make sure you have enough range, the channel is not overcrowded by neighbouring wifi devices and you are not too far away from the router.

Comment: Nope, this is not duplicate. If it is, you would have posted the link too. Please don't mark it as duplicate unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your wireless NIC or router brand, Intel has made a guide on how to speed up wireless connectivity on 802.11n, check out this link:

Source: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005544.html